change in one dropdownlist according to another dropdownlist by ajax in asp.net
I have two dropdownlist one with name and another with contactno on selecting name corresponding contactno want to show by ajax in .net.
Here is my load event [ in which dropdown is bind ]
service.BindDropdownList(cmb_customer, "tbl_Ledger", "Name", "Ledger_Id", "where BranchId = " + Session["BranchId"] + " and Grup = 'CUSTOMER'", "SELECT CUSTOMER");
service.BindDropdownList(cmb_contactno, "tbl_Ledger", "ContactNo", "Ledger_Id", "where BranchId = " + Session["BranchId"] + " and Grup = 'CUSTOMER' and ContactNo != ''", "SELECT CONTACT NO.");

Here is my dropdownlist design code
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmb_customer" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmb_contactno" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>      

Here is my ajax code
$("#<%= cmb_customer.ClientID %>").change(function () {            
    var Name = document.getElementById('<%= cmb_customer.ClientID %>').value;
    var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ name: Name });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Quotation.aspx/GetCustomerDetail",
        async: true,
        data: dataToSend,
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.d.ContactNo);
            if (data.d.Redirect == "YES") {
                Response.redirect("Index.aspx");
            }
            else {
                $("#<%= cmb_contactno.ClientID %>").val(data.d.ContactNo);
                <%--document.getElementById('<%= cmb_contactno.ClientID %>').sele = data.d.ContactNo;--%>
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            // Handle any errors
            $('#result').html('<p>An error occurred</p>');
        },
        complete: function () {
            // Hide the loading indicator
            $('#loadingOverlay').hide();
        }
    });
});

Here is my webmethod code
[WebMethod]
public static QuotationModel GetCustomerDetail(int name)
{
    Services service = new Services();
    QuotationModel quotationModel = new QuotationModel();
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["BranchId"] == null)
    {
        quotationModel.Redirect = "YES";
        return quotationModel;
    }
    else
    {
        string qryGetCustomerDetail = "";                
        qryGetCustomerDetail = " select * from tbl_Ledger where Ledger_ID = " + name + "";                                
        DataTable dtGetCustomerDetail = new DataTable();
        dtGetCustomerDetail = service.GetDataTable(qryGetCustomerDetail);                
        quotationModel.ContactNo = dtGetCustomerDetail.Rows[0]["Ledger_ID"].ToString();                
        quotationModel.Redirect = "NO";
        return quotationModel;
    }
}


GetCustomerDetail returns JSON ?

@Mate it is storing data in model class and that data is passing in ajax. In alert value getting perfect, but in contactno is not showing getting value

Could you add output for alert(data.d.ContactNo) or console.log(data.d.ContactNo) ?  Maybe you could avoid select * in qryGetCustomerDetail , get just columns you need.  Your return quotationModel.ContactNo = dtGetCustomerDetail.Rows[0]["Ledger_ID"] ... why not ["ContactNo"]  ?

@Mate I tried with contactno also still same thing happening, didn't select that data also.

You must set an existing value. Try $("#mydropdownlist").val("thevalue").change();

@Mate can you elaborate by code?

It's just a data verification, check manually if you set a value that exists in your cmb_contactno
